# make play-json read the empty string as None for a type of Option[T]

Tags: scala, playframework, scala-option, play-json

I'm attempting to parse json from the GitHub API with play-json, and encountering a problem with the `merge_commit_sha` field on Pull Requests (incidentally, I know this field is deprecated, but don't want to discuss that in this parsing problem!). Unfortunately `merge_commit_sha` field comes back as the empty string in some cases:

```
"merge_commit_sha": ""
```

This is how the field is [declared in my case class](https://github.com/rtyley/play-git-hub/blob/24db961/src/main/scala/com/madgag/scalagithub/model/PullRequest.scala#L119):

```
merge_commit_sha: Option[ObjectId],
```

I have an [implicit `Format[ObjectId]`](https://github.com/rtyley/play-git-hub/blob/25f2c4c7/src/main/scala/com/madgag/scalagithub/package.scala#L25-L34), which does not tolerate the empty string, because that's not a valid value for a Git hash id. I'm also using a play-json macro-generated `Read[PullRequest]`, which I'd like to keep on using, in preference to individually declaring reads for every single field on pull requests.

As I've declared the field to be an Option, I'd like `"merge_commit_sha": ""` to be read as the value `None`, but this is not what currently happens - a string is present, so the `Format[ObjectId]` is invoked, and returns a `JsFailure`.

One thing I tried was declaring an implicit `Format[Option[ObjectId]]` with the required behaviour, but it didn't seem to get used by the macro-generated `Read[PullRequest]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a custom [Reads and Writes](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaJsonCombinators#reads) yourself.

Using `Json.format[MyType]` uses a Scala macro. [You may be able to hook into that](http://einstein.sv.cmu.edu:9000/@documentation/ScalaJsonInception). Although, 'extending' a macro for this one `case class` just seems wrong.

Custom Reads and Writes might be a little 'boilerplate-like' and boring, but they have their upsides.

For example if your json has a bunch of new fields on it, you wont get a `JsError` when validating or transforming it to a `case class`. You only take what you need from the JSON and create objects. It also allows for a separation between your internal model and what you're consuming, which in some cases is preferred.

I hope this helps,

Rhys

---

**EDIT**

After using some other JSON libs I may have found what you are looking for.
I know the question was asking specifically after Play JSON.

If you're able to move away from Play JSON, Look at [spray-json-shapeless](https://github.com/fommil/spray-json-shapeless) specifically `JsNullBehaviour` and `JsNullNotNone` [REF](https://github.com/fommil/spray-json-shapeless/blob/master/src/main/scala/fommil/sjs/FamilyFormats.scala#L355).

Comment: "You have to define a reads yourself." - To clarify, are you saying I need to manually define the Read[PullRequest] myself, as there's no way to use the macro-generated Read[PullRequest]? This is unfortunate, given the large number of fields on PullRequest.

Comment: Why has this been downvoted, please comment and I can update my answer

Comment: As it happens, I haven't downvoted this answer, although I personally felt it did fall short of being useful - as I stated in my question, I'm interested to know if a solution exists that allows me to continue to use an auto-generated Read[PullRequest] while adapting the parsing of the Option[ObjectId] field within. So a great answer would either give a clever solution which makes that possible, or explain with a bit of justification why such a thing is definitely _not_ possible.